# Why is there a cycle in my linked-list even though it is coded to exit beforehand?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am writing code to solve the following Linked List problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/

To summarise, it is to swap adjacent nodes in a linked list.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def swapPairs(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if not head or not head.next: 
            return []
        
        prev= head
        nex=head
        connector= None
        output = head.next
        count = 0 

        while prev:
            curr = nex.next
            if count>=1: 
                connector.next = curr  
            nex = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            connector = prev
            prev=nex
            count +=1
        
        return output
```

If I run the `input [1,2,3,4]`, I get a `Error - Found cycle in the ListNode`. However when I run the above code on paper with this input, it works like a charm! And exits when it is supposed to- with NO cycle. Any ideas where this supposed cycle is happening?

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: In particular, step through the code with a debugger and on paper in parallel and see where they diverge

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link sabik, I'll try that!

Comment: Can you also share the entire code? the initialization of the list, everything.

Comment: Hi Marcel, this is the entire code, what did you mean by initialisation of the list? I believe this is something Leetcode does in the background. Because if you run a list through the above code in an IDE you would get other errors.

Comment: @sabik, typically I would use print statements, which is helpful for debugging. but for linked-lists I am struggling to 'print'. As I mentioned in my comment above, Leetcode does some background processing so you can pass a list as argument in the above code, which you otherwise can't do on an IDE, and as a result I can't really print

Comment: @PatrickChong I posted an answer showing some of the bugs that needs to be fixed.  It's just a matter of following the code and seeing what changes it makes to the list (and what assumptions it makes).

Comment: @PatrickChong, what I meant is that you said the input is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but I don't see it in your code. You posted the class definitions but not the main script.

Comment: For printing out the nodes, you may need to define a `__str__` and/or `__repr__` method on the class; then you'll be able to print them out. For the next pointer, you may just need to take note of the addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're keeping much more state than you need for this problem.  For example, `count` is completely unnecessary.  Instead of checking `count >= 1`, all you need is `connector is not None`.  The only state you really need from one iteration to the next is the next node to swap, and possibly its successor (as an optimization to avoid having to multiply fetch it).

Regarding the specific bug that is creating a cycle, consider the very first iteration of the loop.  At the top of the loop, `nex` is equal to `head`, so `nex` references the first node in the list.

It then sets `curr = next.next`, so `curr` references the second node in the list (or is `None` if there is no second node).  It then sets `nex = curr.next`, so `nex` now references the third node in the list (or `None` if there is no third node).  But there's a bug right here.  What if `curr` was `None`?  Then `curr.next` will cause an error, right?  So that needs to be fixed.

But assuming the list has at least two nodes, at this point we have `curr` referencing the second node and `nex` referencing the third node (if there is one).  The list itself has not been changed yet.

It now sets `curr.next = prev`.  Since `curr` is the second node and `prev` is still the first node, it sets the successor of the second node to the first node.  It has now created a cycle:  The successor of the first node is now the second node, and the successor of the second node is now the first node.  The third node (if any) is no longer referenced by the list at all.  In other words, it has not swapped the first two nodes.  It is merely created a cycle between them.

At this point it's pretty much gone off the rails.  Hint:  Swapping two nodes entails changing *three* `next` attributes:  the one that originally referenced the first node in the pair needs to be changed to reference the second, the `next` attribute of the first node in the pair needs to be changed to the `next` attribute of the second node, and the `next` attribute of the second node needs to be changed to reference the first node.  After that, the first node will now be the second node and the second node will now be the first node:

```
... A -> first -> second -> B ...
```

becomes:

```
... A -> second -> first -> B ...
```

So `A.next` needs to change, `first.next` needs to change, and `second.next` needs to change.  No changes are needed to `B`.

I suggest going through the logic, *carefully*, seeing what happens when there are 0, 1, 2, 3, ... nodes in the list.  You will immediately find problems which, having been identified, can be fixed.

Update:  Here's a complete solution (only `Solution` is changed):

```
class Solution:
    def swapPairs(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        prev = None
        curr = head

        while curr and curr.next:
            next = curr.next

            if prev is None:
                head = next
            else:
                prev.next = next

            curr.next = next.next
            next.next = curr

            prev = curr
            curr = curr.next

        return head
```

Note that each iteration through the loop steps through *two* list nodes.  The two updates at the end of the loop, which set `prev` and `curr`, are using the updated `curr` node, which is now the second node in the current pair.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom, just two questions/comments. Firstly, you mentioned, 'what if the second node is None?' - I thought the start of my code "if not head or head.next: return []" addresses this? Or is this not the case?

Comment: Secondly, you mentioned that by setting curr.next = prev, we are setting the successor of the second node to the first (I agree), but then you mentioned this creates a cycle, since the "successor of the first node is now the second node." (I don't understand this)- because if we set the successor of the second node to the first node, doesn't the Node 1 -> Node2 link get replaced?

Comment: @PatrickChong Regarding the "no second node" check:  (1) The initial check at the top of the posted code isn't right, since it returns `[]` if the initial list has 0 or 1 nodes.  But that isn't right for either of those cases.  It needs to return `head` for both cases.  That way it returns `None` if the list is empty, and the list itself if it contains a single node.

Comment: @PatrickChong   And (2) That check only affects the cases where the list contains 0 or 1 nodes.  The check needs to be made for each pair of nodes in the list.  So if the list has 4 nodes, the you check it at 4, then 2, then 0 nodes.  Similarly, if the list has 5 nodes, you check it at 5, then 3, then 1 nodes

Comment: @PatrickChong In regard to your second comment:  if you have node1 -> node2, and then you set node2.next to node1, it has no effect on node1.next, and you have a cycle:  node1 -> node2 -> node1 ...

Comment: Thanks again Tom, I understand the final point now- I misunderstood this before then, as I thought the Node 1->Node2 would disappear.

Comment: I also understand the first comment now. However, I still don't get the fact that we check 4,2,0 if 4 nodes or 5,3,1 for 5 nodes..

Comment: @PatrickChong What I mean is this.  When reversing pairs of nodes, you walk through the list two-at-a-time.  Each time through, you reverse the next pair of nodes, then move 2 ahead to the next pair.  At east step in that process, you need to check to see if you have at least *two* more nodes.  If you have only 1, and try to set node.next.next, you will produce an error since node.next is `None` in that case.  So you start with 5, swap 1 and 2, then move to node 3, swap 3 and 4, then mode to node 5.  At that point, you have to check that node.next is `None`, and that there is no node 6.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks so much Tom that makes complete sense now.

Comment: @PatrickChong Would it help if I added a complete solution to my post?  I could easily add it if it would help.  That way you could see the minimal amount of code that's needed.

Comment: Yes, that would be really helpful! Although (I think!) I get it now.

Comment: @PatrickChong Ok, I just posted it.  Refresh the page to pick up the changes, then look at the end of the post for the code.  I've tested this for list lengths 0 through 5, and it works as expected in all cases.

Comment: I see it now, thanks a lot mate. Appreciate the time and help

Comment: @PatrickChong I just added an explanation after the code explaining how the loop steps through two nodes per iteration - refresh to pick it up (no changes to the code).